# Returning char array from function

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, memory-mapped-files

I have the following:

```
#include <boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost\interprocess\file_mapping.hpp>

using namespace std;

void GetFileContents(const char* FilePath, size_t& size, char* data);

int main(){
    char* data = 0;
    const char* FilePath = "My\\Path\\File";
    size_t size = 0;
    GetFileContents(FilePath, size, data);
    //Now data is incorrect
    return 1;
}

void GetFileContents(const char* FilePath, size_t& size, char* data){
    file_mapping fm(FilePath, read_only);
    mapped_region region(fm, read_only);
    data = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
    //data is correct here
    size = region.get_size();
}
```

Within `GetFileContents`() `data` contains the right information. However, after `data` returns from `GetFileContents`() it contains nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a way to remove the `static_cast`?

Comment: Any reason you're using `char*`s rather than `std::string`?

Comment: A change to the function parameter is not visible to the caller. You can try it with `void f(int x) { x=42; }`. Also, both `fm` and `region` go out of scope and are destroyed when the function exits, unmapping the memory - so you have no data to return even once you figure out how.

Comment: @us2012 I want to avoid string due to constructor overhead. This file is 2GB and I want to parse through it quickly.

Comment: You need to do your parsing while `region` is still alive. Also, I hope you run a 64-bit operating system; on a 32-bit one, it's unlikely you will be able to map 2GB worth of data into memory all at once.

Comment: @user997112: You should worry about writing code that works before worrying about optimizations. Also, the constructor overhead from creating a couple strings will be insignificant.

Comment: Using backslashes in includes is asking for trouble - you may want to use slashes instead, they work in Windows too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
void GetFileContents(const char* FilePath, size_t& size, char* data){
    file_mapping fm(FilePath, read_only);
    mapped_region region(fm, read_only);
    data = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
    ...
}
```

`fm` and `region` are objects with automatic storage duration, lifetime of which ends when the execution goes out of scope. Using their internals after these objects are destructed yields **undefined behavior**.

Another problem is that you are actually trying to change the pointer itself, meaning that your function should take `char** dataPtr` and you should call `GetFileContents(FilePath, size, &data);`.

But since you are using C++, you should consider using `std::string` or since you're not working with null-terminated string, `std::vector<char>` might be more appropriate:

```
void GetFileContents(const char* FilePath, std::vector<char>& content){
    file_mapping fm(FilePath, read_only);
    mapped_region region(fm, read_only);
    content.resize(region.get_size());
    char* src = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
    memcpy(&content[0], src, content.size());
}
```

Comment: @user997112: You pass `char*` when you want the function to change the characters your pointer points to. You need to pass `char**` when you need your function to change the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that data is correct at that point is because it is now points to whatever  whatever region.get_address() points to. fm and region get destroyed when GetFileContents() returns, since they lose scope.

What you need to do is copy the data from region.get_address() into data.

```
size = region.get_size()
memcpy(data, region.get_address(), size)
```

Before that though, you need to either pre-allocate data (e.g. in main) or somehow return data (either actually return it or pass it by reference/pointer) and allocate it in GetFileContents().

Assuming you've allocated data to size_t size before calling GetFileContents, you can do this:

```
char* GetFileContents(...) {
  ...
  memcpy(data, region.get_address(), size)
  size = region.get_size()
  ...
  return data
}


int main() {
  ...
  size_t fileSize = 1024; //maximum size
  char* data = new char[fileSize];
  GetFileContents("file.dat", fileSize, data)
  // now fileSize is the real file size
  ...
}
```

Comment: There of course needs to be a check to ensure that size < region.size(). The code given is just a snippet, not an entire replacement for the function.